# vba excel - How to delineate a cell with multiple times in it?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to separate some data in one cell to multiple columns using the text to columns function. The problem I am running into is figuring out a way to separate a cell with multiple times in it, like so: "9:0011:008:0012:30".
I would like to separate it out into: "9:00" "11:00" etc. If I separate by ":" I'm going to get 9, 00, 11, 00. If I do it by ":**" I'm only going to get 9, 11, 8, 12, cutting off the 12:30 time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will your last value of time always be a 0? So no 8:51? If so you could use a formula like `**:**`, and do another IF to remove the leading 0's out of 09:00 and 08:00 when needed.

Comment: I am unsure if the times will be nice and round like that all of the time, otherwise what you suggested would work splendidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my golf attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strInput        As String
    Dim counter         As Long
    Dim strCurrent      As String

    strInput = "9:0011:008:0012:30"

    For counter = 1 To Len(strInput) - 2

        If Mid(strInput, counter, 1) = ":" Then
            Debug.Print strCurrent & Mid(strInput, counter, 3)
            counter = counter + 2
            strCurrent = vbNullString
        Else
            strCurrent = strCurrent & Mid(strInput, counter, 1)
        End If
    Next counter

End Sub
```

It nicely returns:

```
9:00
11:00
8:00
12:30
```

It assumes that the minutes are always with two digits. You can easily change it to a function, returning `Array()`.

Answer (score 0):

The **TextToColumns()** function requires a Delimiter that is essentially "sacrificed", and you do not have one in those strings! Therefore, the **TextToColumns()** approach is not viable.

I suggest you use VBA string manipulation functions instead:

1. Find the position of the first ":" in the string; call it "p"
2. Extract your first item (the characters from the 1st to the p+2) into an output variable, call it `x`
3. Remove the x from the original string
4. Go to Step 1

Comment: Ah, I could see this working. How would you recommend removing the string from the cell once it has been identified?

Comment: @xeno234 You cal use the `Replace()` VBA function to replace the "x"-part with and empty string: `StringYouAreParsing = Replace(StringYouAreParsing, x, "")` You will run the loop until 'Len(StringYouAreParsing) = 0`